# Compile in Xcode for Windows (console)

Tags: c, xcode, cross-compiling

Is it possible to compile a (C) program for Windows' use, in Xcode?

If I were using tcc on Windows say, `system("cls");` is a perfectly valid line, however in Xcode it is not - since Terminal has no command 'cls'.

Ideally the console window would simulate this, but I guess that's a bit much to ask of Apple - so I would be happy with just being able to compile and build for Windows, then test and run on a Windows machine.

I'm aware that it is possible to use an 'external build tool', so is there one that will build for Windows, on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do it especially with Xcode. Mac and Windows have very different architectures, it is much easier to compile a linux program on mac than that you are willing to do.

But every Mac comes will bootcamp, so if you have a copy of windows you can install it and have dual-os system (or use a vm program like parallels).

Answer (score 1):

[See this LINK](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)"Xcode is Apple's powerful integrated development environment for creating apps for Mac, iPhone, and iPad. " So I think the answer is "NO".